# A surface with first fundamental form $ds^2 = udu^2 + vdv^2$ cannot be locally isometric to a right circular cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

> Show that a surface $\Phi$ with first fundamental form $ds^2 = udu^2 + vdv^2$ **cannot**
> be locally isometric to a right circular cylinder.

**Attempt:**

The coefficients of the first fundamental form are:

$$
E = u , \quad  F = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad G = v
$$

Now for the cylinder $C: \rho(u,v) = (r\cos u, r \sin u, v)$ we have:

$$
E _{cyl} = \rho_u^2 = r^2, F_{cyl} = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad G_{cyl}= \rho_v^2 = 1
$$

At this point, I cannot think of a way to proceed, to prove that these two surfaces cannot be locally isometric.

Obviously, $E, G$ are not equal to  $E_{cyl}, G_{cyl}$ **everywhere**. Is this fact enough to prove the statement?

Comment: First of all, are $u$ and $v$ constants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there exists a (local) isometry $F\colon U\subset\Phi \to C$ from (a part of) $\Phi$ to the circular cylinder. Then $F$ must preserve the Gauss curvature, i.e.
$$
  K(p) = K(F(p))
$$
for all $p\in U$.
We know that the Gauss curvature $K=0$ everywhere on the circular cylinder. However, there is no open set on $\Phi$ where the Gauss curvature vanishes.
One can easily verify this. We can use the following formula
for $K$ for orthogonal parametrizations (i.e. parametrizations with $F=0$)
$$ 
K = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\frac{E_u}{\sqrt{EG}} +\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\frac{G_v}{\sqrt{EG}}  \right)
$$
and just substitute the values $E=u$ and $G=v$.

This is a contradiction and we conclude that there does not exist a local isometry from the surface to the cylinder.

Comment: It isn't mentioned explicitly in the OP's question, but I presume that the coordinates satisfy $u\geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$.

Comment: If the coordinates didn't satisfy that then it wouldn't be a Riemannian metric... but then again the question does not say the form must be a Riemannian metric.

Comment: @ Lee Mosher: True. I guess it's OK to tacitly assume this for this question.

Comment: @Ernie060 thanks! Is there a way to see why this is true without using the Gaussian curvature? In other words, can one reach this conclusion with my approach?

Comment: Your approach with the first fundamental form will not work. Example: consider the parametrizations $x(u,v) = (u^2  \cos v, u^2 \sin v,0)$  and $y(u,v)=(u,v,0)$. They both parametrize the plane but the components $E$ and $G$ of both parametrization are different.